# Is there a way to fix appending float values to dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently writing code that's supposed to read a file that has the dates and magnitudes of the major earthquakes in recent years and return a dictionary where the keys are the dates the earthquakes took place, and then the values are the magnitudes of the earthquakes that happened on that date.

My code currently looks like this:

```
def magnitudedictionary():

earth = open("earthquakes.txt", "r")

magdict = {}
for line in earth:
    alist = line.split()
    magnitude= float(alist[0])
    date = alist[1]
    if date in magdict:
        magdict[date].append(magnitude)
    else:
        magdict[date] = magnitude

earth.close()

return magdict
```

But whenever I try to run the code, I always get a Traceback that says:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/MargaretJagger/PycharmProjects/Homework 6/Q2.py", line 18, in <module> magnitudedictionary()
     File "/Users/MargaretJagger/PycharmProjects/Homework 6/Q2.py", line 10, in magnitudedictionary
magdict[date].append(magnitude)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue is exactly, but I know that it has something to do with the float and the dictionary values not matching up.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a [defaultDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this. Then you can avoid the test and just push into the values.

Here's a simple mockup:

```
from collections import defaultdict

earth = '''7.6 20190801
8.2 20180201
7.1 20190801
6.5 20190801
4.2 20180201'''

magdict = defaultdict(list) # values will default to new lists

for line in earth.split('\n'):
    alist = line.split(' ')
    magnitude= float(alist[0])
    date = alist[1]
    magdict[date].append(magnitude)  #magdict[date] will default to a list if the key doesn't already exist

print(magdict['20190801'])
>>> [7.6, 7.1, 6.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

> the values are the magnitudes of the earthquakes that happened on that date.

Since you are talking of “magnitudes”, plural, I assume that you want to be able to store multiple values per date. That means that you should also make sure that your dictionary values are actual lists that store multiple values, instead of just a single value.

Compare the following example dictionaries:

```
{
    "2019-04-17": 2.1,
    "2019-04-18": 3.5
}

{
    "2019-04-17": [1.7, 2.5],
    "2019-04-18": [3.2]
}
```

The first dictionary only maps the date to a single float. So for every date key, you get a single value. The second dictionary maps to a list of floats. Such a list can only contain a single value, or many (it could also contain none).

When you look at your code that sets the values in the dictionary, you can see that you actually built this with multiple values in mind:

```
if date in magdict:
    magdict[date].append(magnitude)
else:
    magdict[date] = magnitude
```

When there’s already the date in the dictionary, then you want to append it. Otherwise you set the date/value pair directly (which adds the key). It’s just that the way you do it, you are setting a single float value (i.e. the first dictionary type above) instead of a list of floats.

So what you need to do instead is create a list of floats here:

```
if date in magdict:
    magdict[date].append(magnitude)
else:
    magdict[date] = [magnitude]
```

The `[magnitude]` create a one-element list with `magnitude` as the first value. Since the value in your dictionary is now a list, calls to `append()` will succeed and correctly add another value to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the else clause.

It should be `magdict[date] = [magnitude]` and not `magdict[date] = magnitude`.

Answer (score 1):

The python dictionary has a very nice method, `setdefault`, that should help here:

```
def magnitudedictionary():

    earth = open("earthquakes.txt", "r")

    magdict = {}
    for line in earth:
        alist = line.split()
        magnitude= float(alist[0])
        date = alist[1]

        magdict.setdefault(date, []).append(magnitude)

    earth.close()

    return magdict
```

Here is a small bit of documentation on the method in question: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm